# Creating a Microsoft Graph subscription for notification to security/alerts_v2 fails

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-management-api

When I attempt to create a Microsoft Graph subscription for notification to the security/alerts_v2 endpoint, the subscription creation fails with an invalid changeType attribute. I have tried multiple changeType:

- created
- created,updated
- updated

But without success.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was the problem. I have forget the '/' at the end of alerts and subscriptions are not available for alerts_v2.